# performing IP reversing in string

Tags: python, regex, reverse

I am doing codes for performing `IP reversing` of a string.

I have done codes for the same as follows:

```
def reverse(ip):
        if len(ip) <= 1:
                return ip
        return reverse(ip[1:]) + ip[0]

ip = '10.1.2.3'
print reverse(ip)
```

**Output my code:** Now it is giving results as follows:

```
3.2.1.01
```

**Expected output:** Instead that I need results should be displayed as follows:

```
3.2.1.10
```

Please some one help me regarding the same.

Comment: split on dots, reverse the list and join.

Comment: As above, `return '.'.join(ip.split('.')[::-1])`

Comment: Or just `return re.sub(r"^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)$", r"\4.\3.\2.\1", ip)`.

Comment: Its fine , Thanks for your response

Comment: Any reason for not using: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
def reverse(ip):
        if len(ip) <= 1:
                return ip
        l = ip.split('.')
        return '.'.join(l[::-1])

ip = '10.1.2.3'
print reverse(ip)
```

Output:

```
3.2.1.10
```

Comment: Oh excellent, I always forget about the slice reverse! Nicely done.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting tripped up by python's insistence that strings are arrays of characters.  How about converting them to numbers and then reversing them?

```
>>> numbers = [int(v) for v in ip.split('.')]
>>> numbers.reverse()
>>> ip_reversed = '.'.join([str(v) for v in numbers])
>>> ip_reversed
'3.2.1.10'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this,

```
>>> '.'.join(ip.split('.')[::-1])
'3.2.1.10'
```

In function:

```
def reverse(ip):
   if len(ip) <= 1:
      return ip
   return '.'.join(ip.split('.')[::-1])
```